# Get all the substrings from url between two different characters android

Tags: android, arrays, url, for-loop, split

I have a url like this

```
https://example.com/Result.aspx?PaymentID=6543210987654321&Result=NOT%20CAPTURED&PostDate=0305&TranID=4589644171260650&Auth=&Ref=606512084038&TrackID=9105423&UDF1=10.000
```

From this i want to extract strings between **=** and **&**.

Code I used for getting this is

```
    String[] b=new String[10];
         a= weburl.split("=");
         for(i=0; i< a.length; i++)
        {
         b = a[i].split("&");
        }
```

But by using this I am getting only last string which is at last index in array(10.00 at last in url).
I also tried using this

```
    for(i=0;i<=weburl.length;i++)    
   weburl.substring(weburl.indexOf("=")+1,weburl.indexOf("&"));
```

And its only giving out the first substring from url which is in between **=** and **&** i.e. 6543210987654321 ..

But I want all those strings in between..

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the steps to get correct result

- First take substring between first index of `?` to the end
- Split the string using `&`
- Using a loop, split the each entry using `=`
- then get the second part from that array.

**Sample code**

```
    String url = "https://example.com/Result.aspx?PaymentID=6543210987654321&Result=NOT%20CAPTURED&PostDate=0305&TranID=4589644171260650&Auth=&Ref=606512084038&TrackID=9105423&UDF1=10.000";
    String parameters[] = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    for (String parameter : parameters) {
        try {
            String[] parts = parameter.split("=");
            String name = parts[0];
            if(parts.length == 2) {
                String enValue = parts[1];
                String value = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(enValue, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " = ");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I like it better than my solution even :D

Comment: java.net.URLDecoder.decode(enValue, "UTF-8"); can you explain this?  @ELITE can we skip that line?

Comment: this line is to decode the paramters values..as those are encoded in given url string.

Comment: example: `NOT%20CAPTURED` will be converted into `NOT CAPTURED`.

Comment: System.out.println(name + " = " + value);  from this I am only getting last substring UDF1=10.000 @ELITE

Comment: in this `for (String parameter : parameters) {` loop, you'll get all the paramters..

Comment: Yeah in parameters I am getting all of them.but they are like PaymentID=6543210987654321.. and so on.. but in String name and String value getting only last substring.. @ELITE

Comment: Well in String[] parts I have all the seperated strings.. I will try to edit it and get only values excepts names from that array.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    a= weburl.split("=");
 for(i=0; i< a.length; i++)
{
 b = a[i].split("&");
}
```

Try using

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
a= weburl.split("&");
 for(i=0; i< a.length; i++)
{
 b.add(a[i].substring(a[i].indexOf("=")+1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Its working.. but getting = also before the substring.. After changing a[i].indexOf("=")) to a[i].indexOf("=")+1) also.. @Milan Vucic

Comment: did adding +1 fix it?

Comment: Well it's not possible to get the same string with and without +1. try +2 and see what you get, maybe there are some unnecessary spaces or something we hadn't predicted. this should work for the link you provided, maybe your original link is different? Mind posting it?

Comment: Its the same link.. I have just replaced example.com

Comment: And every entry in the List of Strings called b, has this = at the start?

Comment: well then try changing +1 to +2 or +3 since there seem to be one or two extra characters.

Comment: +2 gives array out of bound exception.. Not getting = with +1 now.. Don't know what happened before.. It's perfect.. Thanks..

Comment: No problem. I literally couldn't focus on my work properly thinking why +1 did not work :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
String[] array = url.split("=");
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    String[] subArray = array[i].split("&");
    if (subArray.length > 0) {
        Log.e("VALUE", subArray[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "=(([^&])+)&";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("https://example.com/Result.aspx?PaymentID=6543210987654321&Result=NOT%20CAPTURED&PostDate=0305&TranID=4589644171260650&Auth=&Ref=606512084038&TrackID=9105423&UDF1=10.000");
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }
}
```